# How to read JSON array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am using `jQuery` `.load()` function to load the results from server and append it in my html:

```
$("#content").load('Get/Information?class=Arts&min=1', 
function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    console.log(responseText);
    // parseJSON(responseText);
});
```

In my controller I tried converting my jagged array from the model into a json object and then send it to the client:

```
public JsonResult GetInformation(string class, int min){
    var stdObj = new Student();
    string[][] information = stdObj.GetInformation(class, min);
    return Json(information, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And after this when I check the response through `console.log(responseText);`
I have a jSon like string in the following format:

```
[
["93","Title-1","http://stackoverflow.com"],
["92"," Title-2","http://stackoverflow.com"],
["90"," Title-3","http://stackoverflow.com"],
["89"," Title-4","http://stackoverflow.com"],
["89"," Title-5","http://stackoverflow.com"],
null,null,null,null,null]
```

I am not sure if this a proper jSon, as from what I learn jSon is in name: value pairs, but here there are only values, considering this how can I read this string/array and print in following manner:

**This just a representation(pseudo code) of how I required it to be handled:**

```
for(int 1=0; i<response.length();i++){
    $("#content").html('<h1>'+i.Id+'</h1>'+'<p>'+i.Title+'</p>'+'<span>'+i.url+'</span>')
                 .slideDown('slow');
    // $("#content").html('<h1>39</h1>'+'<p>Title-1</p>'+'<span>http://stackoverflow.com</span>');
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `var dataArray = jQuery.parseJSON(response);`

Answer (score 1):

If your response array is

```
myArray = 
[
    ["93","Title-1","http://stackoverflow.com"],
    ["92"," Title-2","http://stackoverflow.com"],
    ["90"," Title-3","http://stackoverflow.com"],
    ["89"," Title-4","http://stackoverflow.com"],
    ["89"," Title-5","http://stackoverflow.com"],
]
```

you can use

```
for(int i=0; i<myArray.length();i++)
{
    $("#content").html('<h1>'+myArray[i][0]+'</h1>'+'<p>'+myArray[i][1]+'</p>'+'<span>'+myArray[i][2]+'</span>').slideDown('slow');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KX596/1/

Comment: @Someone who edited my answer to include a Fiddle link , FYI , my answer was wrong , and so was the fiddle you posted.Please do check if the fiddle is correct before posting a link here.

This is working code.

http://jsfiddle.net/KX596/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
$.getJSON('Get/Information?class=Arts&min=1', function (response) {
    $.each(response, function(idx, rec){
        $("#content").append('<h1>'+rec.Id+'</h1>'+'<p>'rec.Title+'</p>'+'<span>'+rec.url+'</span>').slideDown('slow');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('Get/Information', { class: "Arts", min: 1 })
.done(function( json ) {
   $.each(json , function(i, v) {
     var id = v[0]; // etc
   });
});
```

Refer to [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)